# Less CSS Extend and Pseudo Classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, less, extend, pseudo-class

I am using the following code:

```
header {
    &:extend(.menu all);
}
```

In the less file I have the following structure:

```
.menu {// CODE}
.menu:after {// CODE}
.menu:first-child {// CODE}
.menu:last-child {// CODE}
```

In the output file, the css for .menu and .menu:after show up. But NOT the code for .menu:first-child or .menu:last-child.

If, however, I change .menu:first-child or .menu:last-child to .menu:first and .menu:last then the css code will show up.

It seems that the hyphen is the problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of LESS are you using?

Comment: i just installed gulp-less today.  How do I tell which version of LESS they are using?

Comment: The code that you've shown should work fine (on all versions that support `extend`). Maybe there is a problem elsewhere.